# What is the meaning of 一端 here?

Tags: grammar

> そのレポートには　報道されていない東京卍會の行状の**一端**が記されています

> in that report, you'll find some of what the Tokyo Manji Gang has been up to that hasn't been reported by the media.

is it a counter or has a different meaning?

Comment: You should check a dictionary. It is a word on its own. https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%B8%80%E7%AB%AF/#je-3879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「一端」means 「一部」, or "a part of". It indicates that the report only contains a part of the actions, i.e. not a complete list.